# implement SQL indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on the backend of an mobile application. I have created the table structure for the app.

How can I implement index for the created tables?
I know there are two types of indexing in SQL. Clustered and Non clustered.

My concern is

1. What type of index should I provide for my tables?
2. What all are the columns should be indexed?
3. Do I need to apply indexing for “unique identifier” type columns?
4. Do I need to apply indexing for primary key columns?
5. How can I evaluate indexing performance?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are whole books written about the subject of indexing a database - this makes the scope of the question much too large. I suggest you start by reading: Finding the Causes of Poor Performance in SQL Server - [part 1](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/).

Comment: It's hard to give a concrete answer without knowing what your data structure looks like. That being said, it's typically always a good idea to apply some level of indexing based on how you are accessing your data.

Answer (score 5):

I would **always** recommend putting a clustered index on your tables - it just makes everything faster ([see Kimberly Tripp's blog post on this](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) ).

A **good** clustered index is:

- narrow
- unique
- stable
- ever-increasing

and so a column like `ID INT IDENTITY` is perfect that way (again: [See Kimberly Tripp's blog post on WHY those properties are vitally important to a clustering index](http://sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-again!.aspx) ).

Next, I would put a non-clustered index on any foreign key columns. That speeds up JOINs and other operations relating to referential integrity.

Then **STOP** - let your app run, observe, measure performance. How does it behave? Take profile log to see what queries are executed and which of those are overly heavy on I/O and/or CPU time.

Then go about and optimize those queries - maybe adding an index here and there to speed up one or two queries. Then observe and measure again - repeat ad infinitum.

To learn **a lot more** - [go read Kimberly Tripp's blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/) and watch videos of her presentations at conferences - she's the ***Queen of Indexing*** for SQL Server and her knowledge and insights are vast and priceless. Read her stuff, reflect - use it.

Comment: "let your app run, observe, measure performance" - well put, sir.

Answer (score 0):

for a table you can create 1 clustered index and 999 non-clusterd indexes from sql 2008 onwards.

remeber that if table contains primary key on any column then automatically clustered index will be created.
if table doen't contain any primary key then create clustered index on integer data type column.
remember that if table contains unique constraint automatically non-clustered index will be created on those unique constraint columns.

finally if your table doesn't contain any primary key then create clustered index on any of integer data type column.

then coming to non-clustered indexes if your table contains unique constraints then automatically non-clustered index will be created other wise leave it i.e don't create non-clustered indexes.because too many non-clustered indexes leads to performance problems in future i.e day by day data will be increased.

after creating table , then u r going to use this table in queries . in those queries you may write where condition , for where condition column only u have to create non-clustered index.

always remember you cannot expect performance improvement with non-clustered indexes if  table doens't contain clustered index.

one more point is always try to use 1 clustered index and maximum 5 to 7 non-clustered indexes per table.

don't create non-clustered index for all columns in a table.

Comment: *"you cannot expect performance improvement with non-clustered indexes if table doens't contain clustered index"* This is plainly, woefully wrong.

Comment: And please, edit your question. There is neither an **"r"** nor an **"u"** word in English. This isn't Twitter. You can write an answer up to 30 thousand characters.